# How would I access the pdf generated by Webform's Attachment PDF in a custom Webform Handler?

Tags: webforms, files, emails

I have created a custom Webform Handler that takes the files uploaded by the user on a Webform and uploads them to the third-party file management system Box via Box's API.  I want to also upload the Attachment PDF that is generated but I don't know how to get the file programmatically.  I can click on the pdf links generated and they successfully download as expected.  However, if I try to load that file programmatically, it is empty.  If I manually navigate to the given path... there is nothing there.  Where does this file live?  How do I load it into my code?  The link that is generated is: /webform/[form_id]/submissions/[submission_id]/attachment/[attachment_field__machine_name]/attachment.pdf

Comment: The included remote post handler can include files as encoded data. Have a look at how it does this.